# inline editing todo list can't change input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think I missed something but don't know what is it, I know value={this.text} will bind the state's value, but since this is inline editing, I want to fill the input field with its existing value instead of blank.

http://jsbin.com/fugowebovi/1/edit

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      isEditing: false
    };
    this.onClickEdit = this.onClickEdit.bind(this);
    this.onSaveEdit = this.onSaveEdit.bind(this);
    this.onTextChanged = this.onTextChanged.bind(this);
  }
  onClickEdit(){
    this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing});
  }
  onSaveEdit(){
    this.setState({
      text: this.state.text, 
      isEditing: false
    });
  }
  onTextChanged(e){
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  }
  render(){
    return(

      <li>
      {this.state.isEditing ? '' : <span>{this.props.item}</span>}

      {this.state.isEditing ? <span><input value={this.props.item} type="text" onChange={this.onTextChanged}/></span> :''}
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      {this.state.isEditing ? '' : <button onClick={this.onClickEdit}>Edit</button>}

      <button onClick={this.onSaveEdit}>Save</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

now the problem is it blocked the keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the value of props and change the value of the local state. That is why the input value is not changed

Try this:

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super()
    this.state = {
      text: props.item,
      isEditing: false
    };
    this.onClickEdit = this.onClickEdit.bind(this);
    this.onSaveEdit = this.onSaveEdit.bind(this);
    this.onTextChanged = this.onTextChanged.bind(this);
  }
  onClickEdit(){
    this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing});
  }
  onSaveEdit(){
    this.setState({
      isEditing: false
    });
  }
  onTextChanged(e){
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  }
  render(){
    return(

      <li>
      {this.state.isEditing ? '' : <span>{this.state.text}</span>}

      {this.state.isEditing ? <span><input value={this.state.text} type="text" onChange={this.onTextChanged}/></span> :''}
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
      {this.state.isEditing ? '' : <button onClick={this.onClickEdit}>Edit</button>}

      <button onClick={this.onSaveEdit}>Save</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: pls adda jsbin / fiddle link?

Comment: I know what have u changed but can you add explanation? it helps other people too.

Comment: @Jay Okey, I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Change `<input value={this.props.item} type="text" onChange={this.onTextChanged}/>` to

`<input value={this.state.text} type="text" onChange={this.onTextChanged}/>`

As you are building a controlled component, you should provide it with its current text as value. See [Controlled component in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: this will clear the input text, I want it to be remain.

Comment: Then you should do this.setState({'text':this.props.item}) using componentDidMount lifecyle event

Comment: see in my jsbin link I pass the name from another component, how does componentDidMount help to resist the name to the input?